# i'm having trouble with permission overwrite in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

i am creating a "ticket bot" in discord.js and have got most of it working but need help with `permission overwrites`

the discordjs guide shows this code  but when run it creates the channel but does not do permissions.

```js
        guild.createChannel('new-channel', 'text', [
            {
                id: guild.defaultRole.id,
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
            {
                id: user.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Extra commas are present (fourth line, eighth line, ninth line). Try removing them first.

Comment: that worked, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had extra commas that my linter added, with 11.5 you need to add `permissionOverwrites`

```js
        guild.createChannel('new-channel', 'text',
          permissionOverwrites[
            {
                id: guild.defaultRole.id,
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
            },
            {
                id: user.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
            }
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Quick note that not using the `options` parameter is deprecated as of 11.5.0. It would follow the name parameter and look like `{ type: 'text', permissionOverwrites: [ ... ] }`.